# How to expand a dataframe whoes rows contains list of values?

Tags: python, pandas

```
    c1                c2                             c3
0   [1, 2]     [[a, b], [c, d, e]]      [[aff , bgg], [cff, ddd, edd]]
```

I want the output to be like :

```
    c1   c2   c3
0   1    a    aff
1   1    b    bgg 
2   2    c    cff
3   2    d    ddd
4   2    e    edd
```

Comment: Remember to add what you have as far code, what you have tried to get it to work, what is being outputted and what you want to happen

Comment: Check the dup question .

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.repeat()` and `chain.from_iterable()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': np.repeat(df['c1'].values[0], [len(x) for x in (chain.from_iterable(df['c2']))]),
    'c2': list(chain.from_iterable(chain.from_iterable(df['c2']))),
    'c3': list(chain.from_iterable(chain.from_iterable(df['c3'])))
    })
```

Returns:

```
   c1 c2   c3
0   1  a  aff
1   1  b  bgg
2   2  c  cff
3   2  d  ddd
4   2  e  edd
```

Keep in mind that this is relatively specific to your use case. It assumes that your `c2` and `c3` columns are instantiated with the same shape.